# Python: retrieving multiple files from an FTP server

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, backup, ftplib

[[image]]

I have little problem when trying to get some files from an FTP server using a Python script. I've searched for this, but without success. This is what I have known:

```
session2.cwd("/archive")
maps = session2.nlst()
opslagplaats = input("waar wil je de backup opslaan?")
backupnaam = input("hoe wil je de backup noemen?")
if opslagplaats == "":
    opslagplaats = "C:\\backups eindwerk"
os.chdir(opslagplaats)
os.mkdir(backupnaam)
os.chdir(opslagplaats + "\\" + backupnaam)
for i in range(len(maps)):
    session2.cwd("/archive/" + maps[i])
    os.mkdir(maps[i])
    os.chdir(opslagplaats + "\\" + backupnaam + "\\" + maps[i])
    files = session2.nlst()
    for j in range(len(files)):
        file = open(files[j], "wb")
        session2.retrbinary("RETR " + files[j], file.write)
```

And when I try to run this code, it tells me that the given file can't be found inside `C:\\backups eindwerk\\omglld\\MonMay81345092017196`.

This is how the files are located on the FTP server, and I want to copy/backup them to local place on my PC.

Comment: *"it tells me"* - When does it tell you? What line/statement? On the first file already? Or later?

Comment: Also post an English code!

Comment: As an aside, not all FTP servers accept backslash file separators. You can `import posixpath` and use its `join` function on any platform to the the canonical path separator.

Comment: I don't think you need to translate the prompts... but should example code even have them? A mocked up example removing extraneous crud - but that still breaks for you - is ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One clear problem is this:

```
os.mkdir(maps[i])
```

It will work on the first pass. But on later, you will be creating a subfolder of the previous subfolder. You must be using a full path, like in the `os.chdir`:

```
os.mkdir(opslagplaats + "\\" + backupnaam + "\\" + maps[i])
```

(or pop out of subfolder at the end of the loop).

---

Anyway, why do you reinvent the wheel? Use existing solutions for recursive download:
[Downloading a directory tree with ftplib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2605119/850848).

Comment: thanks, now it works :D little things make a big difference i guess.