# Downloading files with specific name from all directories on FTP server

Tags: python, shell, unix, ftp

I would like to download all the txt files from a directory that is located an FTP server. The directory has a very complex structure, that consists in many sub-directories. Each subdirectory has a `md5sum.txt` file.

How can I write in script that recursively download the `md5sum.txt` from each sub-directory? To be more precise :

<> the directory is :
http://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/spot/eQTL/sumstats/

<> a sub-directory with a txt file :
http://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/spot/eQTL/sumstats/Alasoo_2018/exon/

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Python's `os.walk` to traverse this ftp server, although you may not be able to do it as you would a normal local directory. [This GitHub repo](https://github.com/mazdaka/FTPwalk) implements `os.walk` for FTP servers. By what I understand, you can create a new object with the path of your FTP server, but you may have to modify `Walk` function to check if the file name is `md5sum.txt`, and if it is, then download it. You could use something like the python `requests` library to download the file.

Comment: You cannot *"use Python's `os.walk` to traverse this ftp server"*. You of course might use `os.walk`-like function. But not `os.walk`.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way please to do the same task by using shell scripts ?

Answer (score 1):

Start here: [Downloading a directory tree with ftplib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2605119/850848#10658814)

Just add filter for your specific file name before the file download:

```
if file == "md5sum.txt":
    with open(os.path.join(destination,file),"wb") as f:
        ftp.retrbinary("RETR "+file, f.write)
```