# ftplib.error_perm: 550 Permission denied when downloading files

Tags: python, windows, file, server, ftp

I am running an FTP server with python 3.X on a windows 10 computer. I have a script where I can upload a whole directory into my server. This works with no issue. However when I try to download the respective folder/files I am given the *error ftplib.error_perm: 550 Permission denied*. I have checked that the current working directory (CWD) is correct and that the files do exist on the server. What could the issue be? Here are my `server.py`, `download.py`, and `uploader.py` scripts:

`Server.py`

```
from pyftpdlib.authorizers import DummyAuthorizer
from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
from pyftpdlib.servers import FTPServer


# The port the FTP ServerFiles will listen on.
# This must be greater than 1023 unless you run this script as root.
FTP_PORT = 2121
# The directory the FTP user will have full read/write access to.
FTP_DIRECTORY = "ServerFiles"


def main():
    authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()

    # Define a new user having full r/w permissions.
    authorizer.add_user('MirOS-Client', 'client@miros', FTP_DIRECTORY, perm='elradfmw')
    authorizer.add_user('MirOS-Admin', 'admin@miros$358', FTP_DIRECTORY, perm='elradfmw')

    handler = FTPHandler
    handler.authorizer = authorizer

    # Define a customized banner (string returned when client connects)
    handler.banner = "Connection secured to MirOS-Server."

    address = ('IPADDRESS', FTP_PORT)
    server = FTPServer(address, handler)

    server.max_cons = 256
    server.max_cons_per_ip = 5

    server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`Downloader.py`

```
import ftplib

FTP_HOST = "IPADDRESS"
FTP_USER = "MirOS-Client"
FTP_PASS = "client@miros"

# Connecting to ServerFiles and logging in
ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect(FTP_HOST, 2121)
ftp.login(FTP_USER,FTP_PASS)

# force UTF-8 encoding
ftp.encoding = "utf-8"
# the name of file you want to download from the FTP ServerFiles
print(ftplib.FTP.dir(ftp))
filename = "folder"
with open(filename, "wb") as file:
    # use FTP's RETR command to download the file
    ftp.retrbinary(f"RETR {filename}", file.write)


# quit and close the connection
ftp.quit()
```

`Uploader.py`

```
import ftplib
import os

# FTP ServerFiles credentials
FTP_HOST = "IPADDRESS"
FTP_USER = "MirOS-Admin"
FTP_PASS = "admin@miros$358"


def upload_dir(ftp, path):
    for name in os.listdir(path):
        local_path = os.path.join(path, name)
        if os.path.isfile(local_path):
            print(f"  uploading file {name} ...", end="")
            with open(local_path, 'rb') as file:
                ftp.storbinary(f'STOR {name}', file)
            print(" done.")
        elif os.path.isdir(local_path):
            print(f"making directory {name} ...", end="")
            try:
                ftp.mkd(name)
            except:
                print(" already exists.", end="")
            print(" navigating into ...", end="")
            ftp.cwd(name)
            print(" done.")
            upload_dir(ftp, local_path)
            print(f" navigating up ...", end="")
            ftp.cwd('..')
            print(" done.")


ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect(FTP_HOST, 2121)
ftp.login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASS)

upload_dir(ftp, 'updatefiles')  # your local directory path

ftp.quit()
```

Any ideas??

Comment: From the wording of your question ("when I try to download the respective *folder*") and your code (`filename = "folder"`), it looks like you assume that  `ftp.retrbinary` can download a *folder*. It cannot. It can download a file only (the same way the `ftp.storbinary` can upload a file only and your needed to take care of the directories in the `Uploader.py` yourself).  See [Downloading a directory tree with ftplib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2605119/850848).